# Swiftスクリプトからtouchコマンドを実行する方法について。

Tags: swift, macos

Swiftスクリプトから `touch` コマンドを実行したいと考えています。

以下の質問のベストアンサーを参考に、Swiftスクリプトでターミナルコマンドを実行するところまではできました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971240/how-do-i-run-an-terminal-command-in-a-swift-script-e-g-xcodebuild

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
  let task = Process()
  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
  task.arguments = args
  task.launch()
  task.waitUntilExit()
  return task.terminationStatus
}

shell("pwd")
shell("ls")
shell("touch -t 2001020304 '/Users/myname/sample.txt'") // sample.txtのタイムスタンプを変更する
```

上記を `sample.swift` として保存し、ターミナルから `$ swift sample.swift` を実行すると
`pwd` と `ls` のコマンドは正常に実行されるのですが、目的の `touch` コマンドのところで以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
env: touch -t 2001020304 '/Users/myname/sample.txt': No such file or directory
```

ターミナルに直接このコマンドを入力すると、期待した通りにタイムスタンプが「2020年1月2日3時4分」に変更されるので、コマンド自体は間違っていません。

```
$ touch -t 2001020304 '/Users/myname/sample.txt'
```

ファイルのパスのシングルクォーテーションを外してみたりしましたが、結果は同じでした。
どうすれば正常にコマンドを実行させられるでしょうか。
環境は、macOS Mojave, Swift 5.1.3です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shell("touch -t 2001020304 '/Users/myname/sample.txt'")
```

引数を全部１つの文字列として渡してしまっているからですね。

```
/usr/bin/env "touch -t 2001020304 '/Users/myname/sample.txt'"
```

（実際にはシェルの展開が入るので厳密ではないですが）簡単にすると上記のように解釈されてしまっています。（touchから.txtまでが１つの引数になっている）

`shell(_: String...)`はStringの可変長引数を取るので最終的にStringの配列として`task.arguments`に渡されます。

`task.arguments`が配列を取るのは、引数１つ１つを区別できるようにするためです。

なので下記のようにコマンドも含めて引数１つ１つをそれぞれ別の文字列として渡します。
この場合、引数の区切りは自明なのでディレクトリのパスをわざわざクオーテーションで囲う必要はありません（空白が含まれていても）。

```
shell("touch", "-t", "2001020304", "/Users/katsumi/sample.txt")
```